# How do you add a new character per line in a loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if the title makes sense, but I'm trying to figure out how to make a loop in javascript that would add a character each time it loops. Say for example I want to add a "0" for each line, so the output would look like this...

0

00

000

0000

This is what I have so far

```
var count;
document.write("Starting Loop" + "<br />");
for(count = 0; count < 4; count++){
  document.write("0");
  document.write("<br />");
}
document.write("Loop stopped!");
```

Comment: a) use a second, nested loop to write variable number of zeros or b) output a variable with a growing string instead of the literal `"0"`

Comment: So build a string and keep adding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't use `document.write`, but here's a solution with the same structure:

```
var count;
var str = '0';
document.write("Starting Loop" + "<br />");
for(count = 0; count < 4; count++, str += '0'){
  document.write(str);
  document.write("<br />");
}
document.write("Loop stopped!");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hz2d/)

Answer (score 0):

If the character you want added does not change then I suggest something like:

```
   var count;
   var s = "0";
   var endChar = "0"
   document.write("Starting Loop" + "<br />");
   for(count = 0; count < 4; count++){
       document.write(s);
       document.write("<br />");
       s += endChar;
   }
   document.write("Loop stopped!");
```

Answer (score 0):

So build a string and keep adding to it

```
var s = "0";
console.log(s);
for(var count = 1; count < 4; count++){
    s = s + "0";
    console.log(s);
}
```